# Rails: paginate association with to_json/to_xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, json, activerecord, pagination

I have a model called Playlists which has_and_belongs_to_many :songs

In my PlaylistController I call respond_with(@playlist, :include => :songs) so I can return both json and xml output.

However, some playlists have hundreds of songs. So I would like to let the caller send ?limit=X&offset=Y with the call (with default values 25 and 0 respectively). But how I do pass this limit and offset to the association during serialization? I tried

@playlist.songs = @playlist.songs.limit(l).offset(o)

But that had some unfortunate results. :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

I added methods to paginate the model with the collection and retrieving the paginated collection:

```rb
# models/playlist.rb
def paginate_songs(limit, offset)
    @paginated_songs = Array.new
    songs.limit(limit).offset(offset).each do |song|
        @paginated_songs << song
    end
end

def paginated_songs
    return @paginated_songs
end
```

The I added some logic to the controller which will paginate the object and include the paginated collection in the response:

```rb
# controllers/playlists_controller.rb
@playlist.paginate_songs(l, o)
respond_with(@playlist, :methods => [ :paginated_songs ])
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a task for a pagination library. We are using will_paginate. Our call then looks like:

```
collection.paginate page => 2, :per_page => 10
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this would not change the `@playlist.songs` collection used by the `to_xml` or `as_json` methods which are called by `render_with` as far as I know. Or maybe I am missing something? How do you suggest I use it on my `@playlist` object to paginate the `songs` collection associated with it?